# mysqldump: Got error: 2049: Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to dump a database from a server that uses the old password hash. It's a shared server and I am unable to change the user's password to the new hash.

Attempts with MySQLWorkbench fail with the error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 2049: Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled) when trying to connect
```

Does anyone have a solution?

PS, in the end I *did* get SSH access to the server, so I was able to run mysqldump there. But in absence of that I don't know another way.

Thanks for insight.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use a newer or equal version as 5.7.5 as client, you can add the parameter [`--skip-secure-auth`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_secure-auth) to mysqldump. But since this is deprecated and not supported in newer version, it's best to [migrate away from Pre-4.1 Password Hashing and the mysql_old_password plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-upgrades.html)

Comment: Great idea; however, I'm not the dba for this server :-\